# Is there a Drupal module that allows a user to create a slideshow for individual pages?

Tags: drupal, slideshow

I'm wondering if there is a module out there that allows someone to create a slideshow as he's creating a page? In other words, a set of fields is provided such as image (with the ability to add as many images to the slideshows as I want), and text for each image, title and body of the page, etc. The page is created and a slideshow for that page as well.

Much appreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Views Slideshow: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

Answer (score -1):

there are hundreds out there that do this. go to drupal.org and to the modules section. many integrate nicely with images, imagecache, imagefield and even views.